# Removing a class in PHP

Tags: php, reflection

Is it possible to remove a class in PHP after defining it? For example:

```
class Test { }

<something>('Test');
$test = new Test(); // <- not working because there is no class "Test"
```

Comment: What do you mean by removing ???

Comment: I am a bit afraid to ask, but... Why?

Comment: @bazmegakapa, I have some legacy code that needs to be executed only under certain circumstances. I'm determining those circumstances using methods from new classes. If I determine that the legacy code must be executed instead of the new code, I need to remove the classes (some of which have the same name) so they can be taken over by the legacy code.

Comment: @KingCrunch, it's *very* far from ideal, but better than any alternative I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @Radu Can't you create a factory that will instantiate the right class? (haven't downvoted)

Comment: @bazmegakapa, unfortunately no... They're called the same... I have a `User` class, and they have a `User` class. Once mine is included in order to determine if their code should run, I'm stuck, I can't use theirs now. And I can't use namespaces either.

Comment: @Radu Use namescapes to avoid conflicting names? `\newCode\User` could be the new class.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, the server runs PHP 5.2 unfortunately.

Comment: @Radu You seem to be pretty damned.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, believe me, I wouldn't come to the conclusion that *removing* a class is the best way to do things unless I really can think of nothing else. The only other alternative would be to rename all the new classes just to support this little exception, which is something I really want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple words, No you can not remove the class once you loaded in the script.

If you explain why you need this, you may found any solution.

Comment: Added explanation to the question.

Comment: But you can remove methods, constants, functions with runkit. Why can't you remove classes?! ;P

Comment: @Radu: You can use the [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to ensure that classes name does not conflict

Comment: @meze, this is ugly to begin with... If I add runkit to the process, it starts to become monstrous.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use namespaces, because the server runs PHP 5.2.